# Слово "самость"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Иногда в литературе встречаю слово "самость", но мне оно режет слух. Литературное вообще это слово или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово вполне литературное, термин психологии, есть во многих словарях, значения  несколько отличаются у разных авторов.
СА́МОСТЬ, -и, ж. (книжн.). Индивидуальность, самобытность, своеобразие. Духовная с. С. личности. (Ожегов).
Сознание своей значительности, преувеличенное мнение о себе (Ефремова)
Бессознательный образ жизненной цели (Карл Юнг). Есть и другие.